# SFML VideoMode::getDesktopMode() is weird

Tags: c++, sfml

I've been using SFML feature (sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode()) and it's acting really strange. I'm on Windows 10 64bit. Whenever I use it the window resizes except there's a gap on the left.

[image]

It's a little hard to see because my wallpaper has a gray bit but you can see on the left that it's got a gap. Ignore how the window looks that's just a window's theme I have.

Comment: When it lets you, make sure you accept your answer so other people can see that you have found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out. I've just finally noticed on the documentation it says that on Windows OS it is weird whilst using that. I've noticed it sets it to the right size but it is exactly 9 pixels to the right. So I've managed to fix it by using:

```
window.setPosition(-9, 0);
```

Comment: Hm, on Linux I get a gap on the top instead